# Using a Subclass With Textfield Delegates

Tags: ios, swift, subclass, uitextfielddelegate

I have a subclass, **CustomCell**, which inherits from my parent class, **CreateEvent**. The subclass describes different cells for the table view cell, which is on the CreateEvent View controller. In one specific cell, I have a textfield but I am having trouble getting the value from that textfield when a user enters into the textfield. I am also having trouble dismissing the keyboard with outside touches and pressing the return key, but I am primarily focused on getting the text from the textfield. I am familiar with doing these functionalities on a normal **swift** file but because this is a subclass, I'm not sure what to do. What I've tried is to use:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    entranceFeeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

.. but this does not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give UiTextfeld delegate in UITableview Delegate method and your CustomCell looks like

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var textField: UIImageView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

}

and  one more thing to implement UITextfield protocol in you view controller.and your controller looks like

```
class CreateEvent: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {

//MARK: - Content TableView Methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.textField.delegate = self // like delegate

    return cell

}

//MARK: - UITextField Methods
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
}
```

i hope this will help

Comment: What exactly is cell in cell.textField.delegate = self?

Comment: Cell is your custom cell which is subclass of UITableviewCell and custom cel mustl contains uitextfield

Comment: Ah I see. And do both lines of code go into the parent swift file? So will the parent swift file recognize that I'm calling the textField from the subclass from CustomCell.textField.delegate = self ?

Comment: i have edit my Answer please check i hope you will get idea

Comment: My only issue is that in the tableView function, it is able to recognize the textField after I declare the self delegate, but in the textFieldShouldReturn func, it does not recognize the textField.